# How do I fill a cell in a grid layout with an image?

Tags: css, grid

I'm trying to insert a picture within a div within a grid layout and I want the height of the picture to always match exactly the height of the div. However I can't get the image to respect the boundaries of it's parent div. Most of the times it overlaps the grid and if I use overflow:hidden it just crops the image. I want it to maintain the aspect ratio.

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-template: repeat(2, 50vh) / repeat(3, 1fr);
}

.wrapper {
    background-color: #A9A9A9;
}

.wrapper > div:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #D3D3D3;
}

.img_div {
    position:relative;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%
}

.img_div > img {
    position: absolute;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    margin: auto;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="pic1">Div1</div>
        <div class="pic2">Div2
            <div class="img_div">
                <img src="https://i.imgur.com/VHtXwib.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="pic3">Div3</div>
        <div class="pic4">Div4</div>
        <div class="pic5">Div5</div>
        <div class="pic6">Div6</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The extra child `.img_div` is probably not needed, but to keep same structure, I updated your css to make it `display: inline` and changed the `.img_div > img` styles, removing `display: absolute;` and changed `min-height: 100%;` to `max-height: 100%;` adding `max-width: 100%;` as well.

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-template: repeat(2, 50vh) / repeat(3, 1fr);
}

.wrapper {
    background-color: #A9A9A9;
}

.wrapper > div:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #D3D3D3;
}

.img_div {
    position:relative;
    display: inline;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%
}

.img_div > img {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    margin: auto;
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="pic1">Div1</div>
        <div class="pic2">Div2
            <div class="img_div">
                <img src="https://i.imgur.com/VHtXwib.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="pic3">Div3</div>
        <div class="pic4">Div4</div>
        <div class="pic5">Div5</div>
        <div class="pic6">Div6</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

You could also leave `.img_div` as `display: inline-block` if you'd prefer, but would need to remove its `width: 100%;` 
Also, you may need to adjust vertical alignment depending on your use case.

Comment: Dont just put a code in your answer, explain what is different about it and how it helps.

Comment: @Studocwho done. I accidentally saved before adding. :)

Comment: The problem is when you resize or zoom in the picture at some point is going to get out of it's grid.

Comment: @HumansAreDead I've updated to add `max-width: 100%;` as well which helps. Wrapping becomes an issue with the 'Div2' text. You may need to accommodate for other content; I'm not sure what your end goal is.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution based on this article here.

https://www.whitebyte.info/programming/css/how-to-make-a-div-take-the-remaining-height

Basically setting every div to display:table and then putting every container inside that div as a table-row. That will fill the rest of the height of the gris

```css
body {
    margin: 0;

}

.wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-template: repeat(2, 50vh) / repeat(3, 1fr);
}

.wrapper {
    background-color: #A9A9A9;
}

.wrapper > div {
    text-align: center;
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
}

.wrapper > div:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #D3D3D3;
}

.img_div {
    display: table-row;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.img_div > img {
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="pic1">Div1</div>
        <div class="pic2">Div2
            <div class="img_div">
                <img src="https://i.imgur.com/VHtXwib.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="pic3">Div3</div>
        <div class="pic4">Div4</div>
        <div class="pic5">Div5</div>
        <div class="pic6">Div6</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```